# Add event is not defined

Tags: javascript

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript--net-7670

the above tutorial tells that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //all our code that runs after the page is ready goes here
});
```

And

```
 addEvent(window, 'load', function(){
        //all our code that runs after the page is ready goes here
    });
```

are same . So i am trying to use addEvent like this :

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

addEvent(window, 'load', function(){
    alert("test");
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="ourForm">
    <label>First Name</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

But i am getting error :
`Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined`

Please help. I am new to javascript

Comment: The tutorial you link to *adds* this `addEvent` function, it's not a standard one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a fast explained misreading of a tutorial

Comment: how to use addEvent correctly?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: The function of the tutorial is very bad. It adds or *replaces* an event listener depending on what's available...

Comment: ia am not going to use that function but at least i should know about the function how to use it and also that its obsolete.

Comment: Do you people think that using jquery in JavaScript functions which is wrapped in an object is good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial contains the `addEvent` function. Please check.

```
function addEvent(to, type, fn){
    if(document.addEventListener){
        to.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
    } else if(document.attachEvent){
        to.attachEvent('on'+type, fn);
    } else {
        to['on'+type] = fn;
    }  
};
```

You can use Jquery events instead of this method.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: i thought it is predefined some where in browser, i am so sorry

Comment: This is a bad obsolete function (the tutorial is probably old). OP should not add it but simply use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Do you people think that using jquery in JavaScript functions which is wrapped in an object is good idea?